# Writing my own C++ Compiler .. stuck on variables

Tags: c++, variables, assembly, compiler-construction, cpu

I am currently working on a c++ compiler for my Logisim CPU in JS, and have now a problem with variables:

I have defined a space in ram to store data/values, and I have defined a space to store addresses to the data space. I have a register nx with a pointer to the last variable, and a register mx with a pointer to the last "data-storage" RAM. But I do not know how to access them, e.g. here:

modified C++ Code:

```
int *pointer_test;
int test;
test = 123;
pointer_test = &test;
*pointer_test = 25;
```

Pre-Assembler:

```
//Allocate new variable       <---  int *pointer_test;
add nx, 1
//Set the pointer pointing to zero
sram nx, 0


//Allocate another variable   <---  int test;
add nx, 1
//Allocate new storage for the variable
add mx, 1

//Let the variable point to the data <--- test = 123;
sram nx, mx
sram mx, 123
```

How do I implement now:

```
pointer_test = &test;
```

I have only the value of &test, saved in nx because it is the last variable declared, but not the address of the variable/pointer "pointer_test" ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to write stack based assembly, like every other C compiler in the last 20 years. What that means is that there is a data area in RAM called the stack, which is a FIFO queue, that grows down. Stacks also always involve at least one register: the stack pointer. The stack pointer points at the current place in the stack where the next thing will go. So, to add something to the stack, you put it where the stack pointer points, and then subtract the size of that thing from the stack pointer.

Another register that is used most often in assembly that comes from C is the base pointer. The base pointer points at the beginning of the current frame. A frame can be roughly compared to a scope in C. So, if I have this code:

```
int a;
{
  int b;
}
```

And a stack that's top is at 0x9999, then `a` will be at 0x9995 (assuming 4 byte int), with the stack pointer now pointing at 0x9991, and the base pointer still at 0x9999. When the new scope is entered, the base pointer is moved to the stack pointer, and then B is put at 0x9991. Then, when the scope is exited, the stack pointer is set to the base pointer, effectively erasing the variables in the lower scope.

I've never heard of the architecture you're programing for, but just know that any two registers will do, but some architectures, like x86, have specific stak registers (`ebp`, `esp` on 32 bit and `reb` and `rsp` on 64 bit).

But to answer the question a little more, it is the compiler's job to know what offset into the stack each variable is, so it can do things like (pseudocode):

```
base_pointer - 5 (Offset for pointer_test) = base_pointer - 4 (offset for test)
```

Comment: I thought that usually stacks start from 0 and increase, it gives an easy way to check whether it's empty without knowing its size.

Comment: @J.N. A stack may start anywhere since multiple threads within a process will have their own stacks and all of them can not start at address zero, an address which most probably will not be in the process address space.  However if a stack data structure is being used with an index, it will typically be started with an index value of 0 to indicate it is empty.

Comment: @Linuxios <laughter> Sorry I was writing to JN.  I think your explanation quite good.

Comment: @RichardChambers: Sorry. I just realized that too and deleted the comment! <laughter with you>

Comment: @TobiasSpringer: What you have to do is maintain a mapping of variable names (`test`) to offsets from the base pointer. So the first variable in a stack frame has offset 0, then offset `sizeof(type_of_thing_before)`, and so on. Note: It is much easier if you maintain a stack where all things are the same size, so it would be good if you stored everything but ints, unsigned ints, and pointers on a heap.

Comment: @TobiasSpringer, typically there would be an indirection type of addressing included in the instruction set so that you could do something like the following: two 16 bit integers are on the stack at stack + 0 and stack + 2 and you want to add them.  assume stack pointer is in a register sp so you would do this mov ax,[sp]+0  then add ax,[sp]+2   then mov [sp]+0,ax which would load the register AX with the first variable, add the second, then store the result back into the first variable.

Comment: Yes, I have multiple types of variables but store them all as 32 Bit because my RAM is big enough ... I thougt about using a unique identifier for each block and name the variables internal _nameoftopblock_._nameofcurrentblock_._variable_

Comment: @TobiasSpringer: No worry, I just added it.

Comment: @TobiasSpringer; I think it's easier if you just use the base pointer.

Comment: @RichardChambers: Exactly. The only reason I didn't give code was I only know x86 assembly, and this certainly isn't.

Comment: @RichardChambars that was clear from the beginning, I just had the problem to get the adress of the variable .. but thanks!

Comment: It is my own assembly, as it is my own compiler and I want to understand everything and generate a cleaner code ..

Comment: @TobiasSpringer: your own assembler? For what architecture? x86? ARM? AMD64? MIPS? etc.?

Comment: @TobiasSpringer, or is it a virtual machine?